# Java streams, create new object based on two different objects

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

What is the best way to create a new object based on two different objects.

I would like to use java streams.

My two start objects

```
public class EventA{
    Long id;
    String name;
    ...
    Long locationID;
}

public class EventB{
    Long id
    String Name;
    ...
    Long locationID;
}
```

And my result class

```
public class Result{
    Long locationID;
    String eventAName;
    String eventBName;

    public Result(...){...}
}
```

I have two object arrays like

```
List<EventA> eventAList;
List<EventB> eventBList;
```

I like to get an array of *Result* objects. Every *EventA* name should be copied to the resultList. If an *EventB* at the same location exists I would like to save the name in *eventBName*.

All I have done so far is

```
List<Result> resultList = eventAList.stream().map(e -> new Result(e.locationID, e.name, null)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I don't know how to pass the value from *EventB* to the constructor

Comment: Can't you just have a common ancestor to `EventA` and `EventB`, since they display practically identical properties? You'd then hjave a `List<EventCommon>` to stream...

Comment: No, it's just to simplify my example. In fact they are completely different

Comment: What do you mean by "at the same location" ? Same `locationID` or "at the same index in `eventAList` and `eventBList`" ?

Comment: resultList should be as big as eventAList. If the location matches (same locationID) I would like to save the name of EventB inside eventBName of the result object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating your `Result`, you can use a stream to iterate on the values in `eventBList` to retain only the ones with the same `locationID` as your `eventAList` value, then take the value you found, and `map()` it to it's `Name` value, or `null` if it doesn't exists:

```
List<Result> resultList = eventAList.stream().map(a -> new Result(a.locationID, a.name,
    eventBList.stream().filter(b -> b.locationID.equals(a.locationID)).findAny().map(b -> b.Name).orElse(null)
)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

For better performances, you can use a temporary `Map`:

```
final Map<Long, String> eventBMap = eventBList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b.locationID, b -> b.Name));

List<Result> resultList = eventAList.stream().map(a -> new Result(a.locationID, a.name,
    eventBMap.get(a.locationID)
)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a working way

I adjust the constructor of the *Result* class to

```
public Result(Long locationID, String eventAName, EventB eventB){
    this.locationID = locationID;
    this.eventAName = eventAName;
    this.eventBName = eventB.name;
}
```

and then inside my java stream

```
List<Result> resultList = eventAList.stream().map(ea -> new Result(ea.locationID, ea.name, eventBList.stream().filter(eb -> eb.locationID.equals(ea.locationID)).findFirst().orElse(new EventB()).get()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following and work on enhancements afterwards (e.g. create a map for eventBlist by locationId as key in order to have faster search)

```
Function<EventA, SimpleEntry<EventA, Optional<EventB>>> mapToSimpleEntry = eventA -> new SimpleEntry<>(eventA,
    eventBList.stream()
    .filter(e -> Objects.equals(e.getLocationID(), eventA.getLocationID()))
    .findFirst());

Function<SimpleEntry<EventA, Optional<EventB>>, Result> mapToResult = simpleEntry -> {
    EventA eventA = simpleEntry.getKey();
    Optional<EventB> eventB = simpleEntry.getValue();
    return new Result(eventA.getLocationID(), eventA.getName(), eventB.map(EventB::getName).orElse(null));
};

eventAList.stream()
    .map(mapToSimpleEntry)
    .map(mapToResult)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```